# How to protect sqflite database when updating flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, sqflite

I use an sqflite database in my app. The database is filled with entries by the users. It is essential that the database is unchanged when I deliver a new app version.

When I deploy a new version of the app as apk to my real phone the database is deleted. Is there a way to protect the database during update?

I wonder if it is the method how I deploy the new app version? I use "flutter install". Maybe the uninstall method removes everything from the app including the database and creates a fresh app directory!?

Comment: Are you uninstalling the previous version when installing the new one ?

Comment: No (not that I know of). I presumed the database would not be touched when I deliver a new app version.

Comment: are you passing a version to the the openDatabase method? You should pass a version number and update it every time you create new tables or update existing ones. https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/migration_example.md

Comment: I make no changes to the database. It is the app that is updated. When opening it checks if there is an existing database and opens it. But obviouly the database is deleted during the update process via "flutter install"

Comment: I found that I can preserve the database via system backup. I forced a system backup. Afterwards the database was restored during the update process.

Answer (score 1):

**flutter install** deletes app and database. The solution is to use streamed install. Instead of **flutter install**, run this: **adb install build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk**. This will update the app and leave the database intact.

You must have sdk platform-tools installed and an environment variable pointing to the platform-tools.

Comment: what is the ios version of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of old database and store it in temporary database and save all the old content in new database and after successful insert delete temporary database.
In short following pseudo code may help:

tempdb.data = getOldDatabaseContent
newDatabase.data = tempdb.data
delete(tempdb)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I wonder why I should have to do this. Preserving a database during app update should be quite normal. As it is when delivering using debug mode.